# Php Summing Array 2 Values Based On Array 1 Value Duplicates

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 Arrays, I need To Sum Array 2 values and then associate them back with array 1 value

```
$records_array = array('314','314','500','2100','2100','3210','2100');
$quantities_array = array('2010','1','2250','1000','1000','950','1000');
```

The results I need for comparative reasons

- Record: 314 Qty = 2011  (key 0, 1 are added together)
- Record: 500 Qty = 2250   (key 2 only)
- Record: 2100 Qty = 3000  (key 3, 4, 6 are added together)
- Record: 3210 Qty 950 (key 5 value)

What I do know is the array keys 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 will match record to quantity they're just in 2 different arrays.

**Just edited, find all duplicate values in records_array and add the same keys in quantities_array, then return the sum of quantities array for each records array value **

What is the best way to iterate through the arrays and return these type of results?

Thank you

Comment: Sorry, but your question doesn't make any sense. Can you provide the expected output so we may be able to understand it better?

Comment: I really try hard to uderstand your question, but it make no sense. What you want to do? sum up the array? just compare? huh?

Comment: Have you tried iterating over the arrays? Assuming no problem conditions (e.g. different sizes), a single `for` one-liner would do it. Or you could do it with a call to `array_map`.

Comment: Just edited, find all duplicate values in records_array and add the same keys in quantities_array

Comment: If you want to sum up array, just use array_sum( $records_array ). Second your array was write in a wrong way, just correct it -> $records_array = array( '314','500','2100','2100','3210','2100' );

Comment: Yes, I need to sum quantities array based on the records array so in example 314 appears 2 times, I need to sum the same keys in the quantities array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php     
    $records_array = array('314','314','500','2100','2100','3210','2100');
    $quantities_array = array('2010','1','2250','1000','1000','950','1000');
    $new_array = array();
    foreach ($records_array as $record_position => $new_array_key){
        $new_array[$new_array_key] += $quantities_array[$record_position];
    }
?>
```

Comment: This unexplained answer generates Warnings/Notices and should not be used by researchers.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($records_array as $key => $val)
  $result[$val] += $quantities_array[$key];
```

Like this maybe?

Comment: This unexplained answer generates Warnings/Notices and should not be used by researchers.