# PHP sum array value based on textual duplicate in another array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays, both will always be the same count length. One has doubles mixed with integers, the second has textual (string only) values. They do correlate so I need them both to stay in order. Sorry no keys to work with (by design).

I need to sum the values where I have duplicates in the array that has strings.

Example

```
$dataLabelGraph = array(3, 8, 1, 4.85, 1, 0.5, 6.01, 7);
$dataCalcGraph = array("Coding", "Web development - Coding", "Meeting", "Coding", "Coding", "Content", "Coding", "Coding");
```

So my algorithm should look like this after

```
$dataLabelGraph = array(21.86, 8, 1, 0.5);
$dataCalcGraph = array("Coding", "Web development - Coding", "Meeting", "Content");
```

I was trying to adapt this solution, from the awesome brain of [Martin D.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2852727/martin-e) @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/22071693/12835769

```
$records_array = array("Coding", "Web development - Coding", "Meeting", "Coding", "Coding", "Content", "Coding");
$quantities_array = array(3, 8, 1, 4.85, 1, 0.5, 6.01, 7);
$new_array = array();
foreach ($records_array as $record_position => $new_array_key){
    $new_array[$new_array_key] += $quantities_array[$record_position];
}
var_dump($new_array);
```

Gives something like this, which is close but I need them to remain in two separate arrays

```
array (size=4)
  'Coding' => float 21.86
  'Web development - Coding' => int 8
  'Meeting' => int 1
  'Content' => float 0.5
```

Any help to get me over the line would be immensely helpful. Kudos.

Comment: Honestly, the data seems much less useful in two arrays (keeping them in one gives nice O(1) access -- tell me the value for `"Meeting"`, for example, and you don't have to iterate to find it. Furthermore, it's one less variable to worry about--two arrays can easily get lost in the shuffle or fall out of sync), but you can always pull out the keys and values using `array_keys` and `array_values` to get your desired result.

Comment: If you *really* want the values in separate arrays (presumably for graphing?), just set `$dataLabelGraph = array_values($new_array); $dataCalcGraph = array_keys($new_array);` but otherwise what @ggorlen says about using one array is very true.

Comment: @Nick yes for a chartjs, I would prefer to keep two arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the "name" and sum as you iterate.  When the loop is finished, split the keys and the values into separate arrays.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/MjcUu))

```
$records = [
    "Coding",
    "Web development - Coding",
    "Meeting",
    "Coding",
    "Coding",
    "Content",
    "Coding",
    "Coding"
];
$quantities = [
    3,
    8,
    1,
    4.85,
    1,
    0.5,
    6.01,
    7
];

$result = [];
foreach ($records as $index => $label){
    $result[$label] = ($result[$label] ?? 0) + $quantities[$index];
}
var_export(array_keys($result));
var_export(array_values($result));
```

Outputs:

```
array (
  0 => 'Coding',
  1 => 'Web development - Coding',
  2 => 'Meeting',
  3 => 'Content',
)

array (
  0 => 21.86,
  1 => 8,
  2 => 1,
  3 => 0.5,
)
```

Comment: Hey that is looking good, I do get a **Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()** and I'll see if I can troubleshoot that first.

Comment: Ensure that your real data has balanced arrays (both arrays must have the same count to be accurate).

Comment: How are these two arrays being populated?

Comment: Acknowledged, yep I was trying to parse in json, that is the label was json format and int/float was array, so I converted and my problem is solved. Thanks for the help, very much appreciated.